# Convert my value from String to Int

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

In my controller, If i give this code it shows error in this line
`int id = Convert.ToInt32(val);` as **Input string was not in a correct format**.

Also i tried  to convert it like this

```
int id = int.parse(val);`
```

then also it shows me the same error.

Here is my code. Did i missed anything.

```
public ActionResult Edit(demo demo)
{
    string val = Request.Form["id"];
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(val);
}
```

Comment: And what is the value of `val` ?

Comment: Why don`t you just pass the ID in the input model ?

Comment: what is value of val ?

Comment: Add a break point and inspect val. Chances are it's null, string.empty or has some invalid characters in it.

Comment: So clearly that isn't an int. Why do you have `.00` for an *id*?

Comment: If it has scope to include decimal places, convert to double first. Also use TryParse instead of Parse so you avoid exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use int.TryParse() to determine if the val is an int.

```
public ActionResult Edit(demo demo)
{
    var val = Request.Form["id"]; //could be an object here.
    int id = 0;
    double dblId = 0.0;

    if (int.TryParse(val, out id))
    {
        //id is an int here!
    }

    if (double.TryParse(val, out dblId))
    {
        //dblId is a double here!

        //you can convert the double to an int if you wish:
        id = Convert.ToInt32(dblId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to code around things like this, and using models is a far safer route than using Request.Form.

If you do have to do this, however, I'd either check the string is not null or empty:

```
string val = Request.Form["id"];
if (string.isNullOrEmpty(val))
    val = "0";

int id = int.Parse(val)
```

Otherwise, I'd use tryParse:

```
int id = 0;
int.tryParse(Request.Form["id"], out id);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you'll never get an error no matter the value you can use double.TryParse

here you go:

```
        string val = Request.Form["id"];
        val = val.Replace(',', '.');

        double tempID = -1.0;
        int id = -1;

        if (double.TryParse(val, out tempID))
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(tempID);
        }
```

this way if your double does not have a . it will first replace the , with a .

and you can always just add an else statement for when the val realy isn't convertable